# Change visual studio caret color

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I am trying the new Visual Studio 2012 dark theme. When moving the mouse of code I cannot see the cursor, since the code background is black and the mouse cursor is black.
How to change the mouse cursor in code files to be white or any other color that is visible against a dark background?

Comment: Mouse cursor isn't black for me (I'm also using dark).  You may need to change your cursor in windows settings.

Comment: It seems they changed this, it's not black for me anymore either.

Comment: As of 2017-01-10 Visual Studio Code also shows a black caret over a black background - the best info I could find is here in this question.

Comment: 2019 - how is this not fixed yet. Is this not a MAJOR issue???

Answer (score 80, accepted):

In Windows 7 I resolved this by modifying my Windows system settings to use the Windows Black (system scheme). The caret I-Beam shape is surrounded by a white stroke that stands out over dark backgrounds and invisible over pure white backgrounds.

Go to Control Panel-->Appearance-->Ease of Access-->Make the mouse easier to use

and choose "Regular Black"

You would think that that the Inverted option would work, but the color remains black over the dark greys of the VS 2012 dark theme. The Regular Black does work well though.

Comment: Perfect! Been wondering about this for awhile but never took the time to look into it. Thanks man!

Answer (score 10):

Just change the Text Select of the mouse to 'Windows Black'

[image]

Comment: As of 2017-01-10 - I had the same problem using Visual Studio Code (aka vscode).  The caret (aka Text Select in the mouse properties) is where one can change the thin-lined black caret (mouse pointer during text select - also when moving the mouse around in a text editor) to something easier to see over a black background.  The solution in this answer works, although at the moment I want to barf when I see that caret so fat.

Answer (score 6):

I could not see the blinking cursor due to a black background as well. The fix in Visual Studio 2017 was to set the Item forground and background colors different.

`Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors > Show settings for: Text Editor > Display items: Plain Text`

It seems the cursor color takes its cue from Item foreground.

Comment: Exactly. Mouse selection cursor has nothing to do with caret cursor in editor. And it seems there is no way to make it different from plain text display color. I fall to option just to make it thicker through accessibility settings.

Answer (score 5):

On a **Windows 10 level** there is a solution for the cursor/indicator/caret with some swag in the form of :

https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/137454-change-text-cursor-indicator-color-windows-10-a.html

**For Visual Studio specifically:**

1. Install the extension **Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2019** from the market: [LINK](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2019ColorThemeEditor) or from within the VS itself --> Extensions --> Manage --> Online (Use the search bar)
2. When this extension is installed open it from within VS by --> Tool --> Customize Colors and then use the search for key word "caret" and change the Foreground and Background colors of the indicator/cursor/caret.

Example: Text Editor -> VsVim Block Caret -> Background

INFO: Look at the image for more guidance *(the search bar is to the right of the save; save and apply icons... outside of the screenshot)*:
[image]

Comment: VsVim has its own cursor color, and this extension is the only way to edit it.

Comment: The Color Theme Editor for Visual Studio 2019 is [deprecated](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=VisualStudioPlatformTeam.VisualStudio2019ColorThemeEditor), use the [Color Theme Designer](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-madsk.ColorThemeDesigner) instead

Answer (score 4):

Changed my select caret to a custom green caret. Now I can always see it, even against the black vs background.

Comment: Please explain how you did this.

Comment: There are many free downloadable caret sets http://www.7tutorials.com/top-10-best-mouse-cursor-schemes-windows
Control Panel -> Hardware -> Mouse -> Pointers -> Text Select -> Browse and select an image you downloaded.

Comment: Thank you @MrFox these are awesome! The Metro one is really nice. There's a v3 if you go with that.

Answer (score 0):

A solution I've found for macOS (up to Mojave) is to modify the VS Code core files.

Open the file `/Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents/Resources/app/out/vs/workbench/workbench.desktop.main.css`.

Paste in this CSS  in that file, doesn't matter where:

```
.monaco-editor.vs-dark .view-lines {
    cursor: -webkit-image-set(url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAABAAAAAQCAQAAAC1+jfqAAAAL0lEQVQoz2NgCD3x//9/BhBYBWdhgFVAiVW4JBFKGIa4AqD0//9D3pt4I4tAdAMAHTQ/j5Zom30AAAAASUVORK5CYII=') 1x, url('data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAACAAAAAgCAQAAADZc7J/AAAAz0lEQVRIx2NgYGBY/R8I/vx5eelX3n82IJ9FxGf6tksvf/8FiTMQAcAGQMDvSwu09abffY8QYSAScNk45G198eX//yev73/4///701eh//kZSARckrNBRvz//+8+6ZohwCzjGNjdgQxkAg7B9WADeBjIBqtJCbhRA0YNoIkBSNmaPEMoNmA0FkYNoFKhapJ6FGyAH3nauaSmPfwI0v/3OukVi0CIZ+F25KrtYcx/CTIy0e+rC7R1Z4KMICVTQQ14feVXIbR695u14+Ir4gwAAD49E54wc1kWAAAAAElFTkSuQmCC') 2x) 5 8, text;
}
```

([source](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/commit/6b6c36f88d8c3bee6372a4f7861cf70395ac1327))

This could be done manually, with a shell script, or with an extension like the [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css).

Restart VS Code. You'll see a warning about Code being corrupted. You can resolve those using the [Fix VSCode Checksums](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=lehni.vscode-fix-checksums) extension.

Answer (score 0):

For those using VsVim might try:
`Tools -> Options -> VsVim -> Block Caret Foreground`.
The default is both f/b colors are same, which makes character under
the cursor invisible.