# How to change Visual Studio's (or any other text/code editor) caret size?

Tags: visual-studio, text-editor

How can I change Visual Studio's (2010 or 2012) cursor/caret **size**?

Something like this:

[image]

*I'm not looking for the Insert Key!*

Comment: " Overwrite -- the "fat" caret that will overwrite any previous characters as you type. " how can i do this?!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12842760/change-visual-studio-caret-color

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Text overwrite in visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089876/text-overwrite-in-visual-studio-2010)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You can change the width of the cursor (caret) although it is a system global setting, not specific to Visual Studio.

*Control Panel -> Ease of Access Center -> Make the computer easier to see -> Set thickness of the blinking cursor*

(This is in Windows 7 - in other versions of Windows you may have to go hunting given how Microsoft like to change things. Alternatively, edit the registry setting **HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\CaretWidth**).

Comment: Very good...this is more and more important because higher resolution screens usually have larger pixel density so default caret is too invisible...thank you

Comment: thanks. It's absurd that nowadays we need to modify registries for these ease of access features :/

Answer (score 1):

The cursor will be bigger as long as it is taller, and it is taller as long as the font size is bigger. So an alternative is to change the font size:

1. Select Options from the Tools menu and in Environment folder, select
   Fonts and Colors.
2. In Show settings for, select Text Editor.
3. Change the font, size, display item, foreground and background
   colors.