# How do you change the cursor font or color in Visual Studio?

Tags: visual-studio

I would like to improve the visibility of the cursor in the text editor in Visual Studio. It is sometimes hard to find the blinking cursor because it is a little on the thin side.

I do not see a way to modify the font/color for the cursor when I inspect Tools>Options>Environment>Fonts and Colors.

I see other instances online where someone asked this question for VS Code, but the only thing I could find for Visual Studio was this question: [Change the text cursor/caret in Visual Studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3894551/change-the-text-cursor-caret-in-visual-studio-2010)

Which is not what I am after. I want to just increase the thickness or height of the blinking line.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could press the Insert key, twice, to temporarily get a large blinking caret.

Comment: Probably not what you're looking for but if you're using Windows, check out `Settings > Ease of Access > Text Cursor`. There's an option to add a text cursor indicator (i.e., highlighter) and another option to change the text cursor thickness. Both options are applied globally including in VS.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine, thank you, that is not exactly what I was looking for, but it is definitely helpful. I may not want a global windows setting, but that I'll live with it if it helps me in visual studio!